# The multi-part identifier could not be bound error message petapoco

Tags: petapoco

I am using  petapoco relationExtensions with the following :

```
Connection.db.FetchOneToMany<Project, UserProject>(x=>x.ID, string.Format(@"
            SELECT * 
            FROM Project                         
            WHERE project.id = userProject.ProjectID
                AND userProject.UserID =" + userID + 
                 " ORDER BY project.Name" ));
```

but having the following error.

> ```
>  > The multi-part identifier "userProject.ProjectID" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "userProject.UserID" could not be bound.
> ```

What is wrong? Am I missing anything?

Project Class definition

```
    private int id;
        public  int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        private string name;
 public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
```

UserProject Class definition

```
int id;
    int userId;
           int projectId;
 public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
 public int UserID
    {
        get { return userId; }
        set { userId = value; }
    }
 public int ProjectID
    {
        get { return projectId; }
        set { projectId = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to join the user project table?

Comment: @Gareth, yes, I need to join them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is a UserProject table; the error is a SQL error because you're not joining the UserProject table and referring to it in the sql. Try this :

```
Connection.db.FetchOneToMany<Project, UserProject>(x=>x.ID, string.Format(@"
            SELECT * 
            FROM Project                   
            left join userproject on userProject.ProjectID = project.id
                where userProject.UserID =" + userID + 
                 " ORDER BY project.Name" ));
```

The relation extensions don't change your sql

Comment: Also you should be using sql parameters here to prevent sql injection. eg; ....where userProject.UserID=@0 ORDER BY project.Name", userID));

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It specifies the second object's key as well as the first.

Notice also the usage of parameters rather than concatenating it into your sql string. That wouldn't give you an error, but it's better to do it this way for a variety of reasons.

**Edit**

I just noticed that you are not actually joining in the UserProject table in your sql. That would be why you got the first error above. Did you really mean something like below?

```
var projects = Connection.db.FetchOneToMany<Project, UserProject>(
               x => x.ID, 
               "SELECT * 
               FROM Project
               LEFT JOIN UserProject ON project.id = userProject.ProjectID                        
               WHERE userProject.UserID = @0 
               ORDER BY project.Name", userID);
```

**Update**

Based on your classes above, you are missing something. I am assuming that you have a one-to-many relationship between Projects and UserProjects (seems like UserProject might be a bridge table in a many-to-many relationship between Projects and Users). The purpose of the `FetchOneToMany` method is to take the 'many' side of the relationship and put all those objects into a list property on the 'one' side of the relationship.

So, you should have a property on your Project class that is `List<UserProject>` type in order for this to work.

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserProject> UserProjects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am having the error message Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: See my edit. Just realized that your sql statement didn't actually join in the userproject table, which explains your first error, and might be related to the second.

Comment: thank you for answering.  I am trying to do something as SELECT project 
                    FROM Project AS project, 
                         UserProject AS userProject 
                    WHERE project.id = userProject.Project.id 
                        AND userProject.User.id = {0} 
                         ORDER BY project.Name", userID).  I think I have not understood how to use relationExtensions and tried the above code.  That may give you a hint of what I want to do.

Comment: Can you show the Project and UserProject class definitions (edit your question)?

Comment: I have inserted the classes definition in the edited part of the question

Comment: One last thing. I see why you might have been getting that other error (now that I see your classes). I was mistakenly putting projectId as the second key, but now I see that UserProject has an ID property too. Since they are the same name, you can just specify it once. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks @patmortech, that was so helpful.